# Mule FunctionalTest - How to access Jersey component to test values aer injected correctly?

Tags: mule

I am trying to unit test a Mule flow which contains a Jersey resource component that receives some parameters via injection using the `@Context` annotation.

I want to be able to test that these values are correctly received and set within my Jersey component.

How can I get access to the Jersey component used within my `FunctionalTestCase` so I can assert those values are correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Components are registered like any beans inside the registry.

Try to locate it with: `muleContext.getRegistry().get(key)` where `key` is the Jersey component `name` or `id`.